# rails app helper hash driving menu list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I want the sites navigation menu to be populated by a hash in the application helper.  I've got it looking right; but the path helpers are not being evaluated (meaning my link tag's href = "root_path" instead of "/").

In my application_helper:

```
    $navPages = { 
    'Home' => "root_path",
    'page2' =>  "page2_path"

    }
```

and in some layout partial the erb is as follows:

```
    <ul>
    <% $navPages.each do |ntext,npath| %>
    <li><%= link_to ntext, npath %></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

So this setup will get the list too look right; but the href's aren't being evaluated. The first list item link tag href = "root_path" instead of the evaluated version of the string "/".... I've tried a few things to no avail.  This is some fundamental lack of understanding the hash value storage and how/when the ruby path helper is being evaluated.  I've tried:
1. removing the quotes from the hash (returned an unknown variable/method error)
2. "#{npath}
3. "raw"
a few other things.

Any direction will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% $navPages.each do |ntext,npath| %>
  <li><%= link_to ntext, self.send(npath.to_sym)%></li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: PERFECT!  Thanks.  That appears to convert the string into a symbol that will be evaluated.  Thanks you!